# What is the difference between a semaphore and an atomic int?

Tags: c++, concurrency, operating-system, synchronization

I mean not from the point of view of there interfaces in C++, but from OS side, what real difference between these concepts.

Tried to google it, but on different resources i just found only very similar description of these concepts.

Comment: Atomic integer is an integer with which you can do a bunch of atomic operations - like addition, subtraction...These operations are not guaranteed to be atomic for ordinary integers on modern CPUs. Semaphore is a locking mechanism to restrict and thus protect access to resources. Yes, semaphore's interface can be implemented using an atomic integer. So it could be said that semaphore is one of the uses for atomics?

Answer (score 0):

an atomic is a value the CPU has to keep synchronized across cores, when one thread modifies an atomic the CPU uses special instructions to guarantee synchronization across all cores.

the operating system is responsible for scheduling threads for execution, when a semaphore is going to be decremented below 0, the thread makes a `syscall` to the operating system to suspend itself until the semaphore is incremented by another thread, then the operating system will re-schedule that thread for execution.

a semaphore is basically an atomic that if you try to decrement below 0 you will be suspended until another thread increments this semaphore, a mutex is basically a semaphore with a value of 1.